# Netezza CSV load ignore comma within value

Tags: netezza

I am loading a **CSV file in Netezza**. One of the columns in this file has value like: `$500,000-$749,999`.

Even though this value is enclosed within double quotes, Netezza is not ignoring the comma. It throws an **error** like - `expected end of row, "999"`.

There are two more columns after this field in the file. I tried adding ***EscapeChar*** `','` but it again gave an ***error that Delimeter and EscapeChar cannot have the same character***.
Have anyone faced similar issue?

**Workaround:**

I can add 2 two more columns in my table, but then it would fail where field do not have comma value in it.

Comment: Thank You @JanSršeň for formatting the question :)

Comment: One update on the Workaround:
i added 2 columns and executed the command to load data into table. 
The command worked fine, without any issues.
I used the ***FillRecord*** option, it assumed that last 2 columns are missing for some records and populated them with NULL.
I stored the data in a temporary table and then populated the main table as required. I did this in development environment.
A solution will be more helpful, as i won't have this workaround option in Prod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the **QuotedValue** option to *DOUBLE*

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/r_load_quotedvalue.html

Also, if all your columns are quoted, you could also set the **requirequotes** option to *true*

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/r_load_requirequotes.html

Comment: Thanks @PaulVernon. It worked with **QuotedValue** option.